# Unique Identifier Changing on 64 bit iOS Device

Tags: ios, iphone, uniqueidentifier, uidevice

Reviewed lots of questions as there are number of questions with same topic but not find with the same issue so posting.

**Issue**

Looking to Generate `Unique Identifier` for `iOS` Device as if user install app and with reinstall   generate same identifier.

**Resolved But Not Working With 64 Bit Devices**

I Used this code for fetching the unique identifier for `iOS` device and it works fine all but when i run it on `64 bit iOS device` it gives different result on every install. Please review if anyone know about the possible solution.

```
- (NSString *)GetUUID {
    @try {
        UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
        return [[device identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return @"00000-00000-0000-00000";
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear, Down voter please comment with the reason of down vote as this will help everyone to improve question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) will stay the same as long as app from the same developer(vendor) are installed on the device.

Thus if user uninstalls your app and there are no other app by you on the user device the [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) will be different when the user re-installs you app.

Apple has made it very clear they don't want developers track devices or installs per device. Thus you can no longer get any unique identifier from the device.

The changing of the [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) could have to do with some re-installing isseu. I've been tracking [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) and dit not see this issue.

Comment: So what will be the feasible solution if i want to get same identifier if the app reinstall on same device.

Answer (score 0):

For storing identifier betweeen reinstalls you may use this code (add SSKeychain to project)

```
/*
 The following method determines the AppName and a uniqueidentifier and store it in the   keychain
 As a result when the user removes the app, downloads it again his JID and password which  are derived from the
 uniqueidentifier don't change.
 otherwide the identifierForVendor method would return a new value on reinstall
*/
-(NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString
{

NSString *appName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];

NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"incoding"];
if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
{
    strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"incoding"];
}

return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this reply will this solution is feasible on first app install if i set the value with key in `SSKeychain` and on reinstall will it give me the same value ? as i di't tried this function till now so just confirming ?

Comment: Yes, after first install this method will keep a value in keychain. And then will retrieve this value

Answer (score 0):

Use keychain Access to solve getting different vendor ID

Simple iPhone Keychain Access

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/03/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html